# NSPredicate&NSSortDescriptor with to many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

I have schema like that:
`

```
class Message: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var content: String
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var sendDate: NSDate
    @NSManaged var sender: User
    @NSManaged var receiver: User

}

class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var login: String
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var sendMessages: NSSet
    @NSManaged var receivedMessages: NSSet

}
```

I need some help with NSPredicate and NSSortDescriptor. I'm sure that's easy one, but i'm in the beginning of learning Core Data Stuff.
So:
I need to do fetch in User table, to receive users that have one or more received or send messages.
I'm doing it like that:

`let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sendMessages.count > 0 OR receivedMessages.count > 0")`
 
And then, i need to sort it in the way that i have users with have talked  recently on top of the table view(send or received Messages)
Should i use min function maybe?
Thank you for answer, I appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

Have you try something like :

```
let sortSend = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath:"sendMessages.sendDate", ascending: false)
let sortReceived = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath:"receivedMessages.sendDate", ascending: false)

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortSend, sortReceived]
```

[EDIT]
My bad, it's not possible directly since it's relationship, so you will have to filter it afterward, with something like :

```
let sortSend = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath:"sendDate", ascending: false)
let sortReceived = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath:"sendDate", ascending: false)

var result = []// result of request, array
var sendMessages = result.valueForKeyPath("@distinctUnionOfSets.sendMessages")
var receivedMessages = result.valueForKeyPath("@distinctUnionOfSets.receivedMessages")

var messages = sendMessages.setByAddingObjectsFromSet(receivedMessages)

messages = [messages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[sortSend, sortReceived]]
```

Your messages will be sorted, you can get back user from them.

It seems too complicated.
What you could do is keep a lastMessageDate on your user, and sort them by that property, it will simplify your code a lot.

Comment: This won't work as `sendMessages` and `receivedMessages` are sets (which represent to-many relationship), not a single instance of a `Message`.